# Setting persistentStoreDescriptions causes no CoreData objects to be saved

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I am trying to ensure that all of our CoreData is protected using Data Protection.  When I try to set a NSPersistentStoreDescription on my container, no CoreData objects are saved.  If I comment out the line indicated below, all objects are saved (and read) just fine.  If I enable the line, nothing gets saved (or perhaps the read silently fails?).  There are no errors generated and there are no logs generated.  I do have the Data Protection entitlement in my provisioning profile (matching completeUnlessOpen).  I've gotta be missing something very basic.

This is Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002)

Can anyone offer any insight / advice?

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "my_app")
    let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

    description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
    description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
    description.setOption(FileProtectionType.completeUnlessOpen as NSObject?, forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)

    // *** ALLOWING THIS NEXT LINE TO EXECUTE CAUSES PROBLEM ***
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Comment: If you have the entitlement for protection specified, why do you need to add file protection on the individual file?

Comment: That's a great question that I would love to know the answer to.  Can you point me to documentation that says this happens by default please?

Comment: I just verified it with `let attributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.relativePath)` and my files are by default `NSFileProtectionComplete`

Comment: Thank you!  Sure enough, that flag is set by default.  I really appreciate your time and efforts on this!

Answer (score 2):

I understand that this question has been asked long time back, but I'm still going to post an answer so that anyone stuck at this problem gets some help.

In the above code snippet you posted in the question, you did not initialize **NSPersistentStoreDescription** with **SQLITE file URL**.

So, it does not know what persistent container it represents. Please refer below working code.

```
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "AppName")

    if let storeDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let sqliteURL = storeDirectory.appendingPathComponent("AppName.sqlite")
        
        //Set Protection for Core data sql file
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: sqliteURL)
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        description.setOption(FileProtectionType.complete as NSObject, forKey: NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
    }
    
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in...}
```

Let me know if this works for you and please accept the answer if it does, so that others will know.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is actually because you're setting options that should relate to Core Data. File protection is done under `FileManager` `setAttributes` function calls.

However, the answer to the underlying question is that you don't need to add file protection to individual files - they're set to the default protection you declare in your entitlement.

This can be verified by printing the output of:

`let attributes = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: url.relativePath)`

Comment: I think you're wrong and the original code is correct,  NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey is an option specific to NSPersistentStoreDescription, meant for this purpose.